# find pattern with two strings/parts/groups and extract them in Android

Tags: android, regex, string, extract, regex-group

i tried to get the 2 strings inside a pattern but i cannot get them.

I have checked several posts and i thought maybe i could access the strings using `.group()` but no luck.

```
private static void addUlrToList(String text){
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("url=(.*?)<br>name=(.*?)<br>");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    while(matcher.find()) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG1, "found");
        for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG1, "? url:" + matcher.group(i));
        }

    }
}
```

It does not even enter the while loop, like if it is not even finding a match with the pattern.

what am i missing?

EDIT:
the input string is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"><html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"><title>Insert title here</title></head><body>OK<br>url=images/cartoons/<br>name=cartoons2_208x150<br>url=images/cartoons/<br>name=cartoons_208x150<br></body></html>
```

Comment: post the input string.

Comment: Debug and inspect matcher object, does it really find anything? And  yes, input string, what are you trying to match?